# SQL Query conversion Vs Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

Here are two tables named by Country and State, I simply want to know
below SQL query to Entity Framework in Lambda Expression using C# or Vb.Net.

```
SELECT dbo.Country.CountryID, dbo.Country.CountryName, dbo.State.StateName
FROM dbo.Country
     INNER JOIN dbo.State ON dbo.Country.CountryID = dbo.State.CountryID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from p in context.country 
join q in context.state on p.CountryID == q.CountryID
select new { p.CountryID,p.CountryName,q.StateName }
```

Comment: Thanks sir, kindly can you write it again in Lamda Expression......with Enity framework

Comment: context.country.Join(context.state, p => p.CountryID , q => q.CountryID, (p, q) => new {p.CountryID,p.CountryName,q.StateName});